# .htaccess | How to attach text or file as header for certain or all files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Searching around didn't find how a .htaccess file could edit/modify certain (.html, .php, .json, etc.) or all files.

*In this example, the code/file is attached as a header for all or certain types of files.*

**example.php**

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**code/file content to attach**

```php
<script>console.log(<?php echo __FILE__; ?>);</script>
```

**desired.php**

```php
<script>console.log(<?php echo __FILE__; ?>);</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I know a little of .htaccess but enough to adapt an example, don't know where to start.

Note: if somebody asks, my current -unnecessary, I think- code:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
SetEnv TZ America/Mexico_City
php_value date.timezone 'America/Mexico_City'

Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ index.php?r=$1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP's [auto_prepend_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file), obviously this only works for PHP.

Add this to your `.htaccess` (or change your `php.ini` accordingly):

```
# modify include_path to prepend.php if needed
#php_value include_path .:/var/www/php/include:/usr/share/php

# the template to prepend to your php files
php_value auto_prepend_file prepend.php
```

Change the content of `prepend.php` to:

```
<script>console.log('<?php echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]; ?>');</script>
```

to use the requested file path instead of the path of `prepend.php`.